# Possibilities to speed up PHP-CLI script?

Tags: php, performance, command-line-interface, audio-processing

I wrote a PHP-CLI script that mixes two audio (.WAV PCM) files (with some math involved) so PHP needs to crunch through thousands (if not even millions) of samples with `unpack()`, do math on them and save them with `pack()`.

Now, I dont need actual info on how to do the mixing or anything, as the title says, I'm looking for possibilites to speed this process up since the script needs 30 seconds of processing time to produce 10 seconds of audio output.

Things that I tried:

- Cache the audiofiles to memory and crunch through with `substr()` instead of `fseek()`/`fread()`. Performance gain: 3 seconds.
- Write the output file in 5000-samples chunks. Performance gain: 10 seconds.

After those optimizations I ended up at approximately 17 seconds processing time for 10 seconds audio output. What bugs me, is that other tools can do simple audio operations like mixing two files in realtime or even much faster.

Another idea I had was paralellization, but I refrained from that due to the extra problems that would occur (like calculating correct seek positions for the forks/threads and other related things).

So am I missing stuff out or is this actually good performance for a PHP-CLI script?

Comment: The first thing you should do whenever you want to "speed up" or "increase performance" is run a profiler to see what parts of your code take the longest to execute, instead of taking a few shots in the dark. It seems you already identified some of them, if you run a profiler, maybe you'll find more. If that's still doesn't work, well every tool has its limit, and maybe you found PHP's.

Comment: PHP performance is always going to be.... I guess the polite word would be "abominable", for that sort of thing.

Comment: Maybe you can try to move the functions that do the editing to a C program and just have php be the middleman :)

Comment: This is a job for a lower-level language than PHP. Write in C++ (or your compilable, non-interpreted language of choice), compile it into a binary and `exec()` it from PHP. Performance gain: unmeasurably large. Or, if C++ is your thing, maybe considering writing it as a PHP extension.

Comment: As much as i love PHP i agree with Tyler, Antonio and Dave. Youre better off using a more general language like Ruby or Python, but even then you arent going to get the same type of performance you might get from compiled C/C++ code. With that said if its a possibility you could try [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) to compile the php down to C.

Comment: @prodigitalson, surely PHP. Ruby, Python, Perl are all bytecode interpreted languages.  PHP benchmarks at 2.5-4M opcodes/sec/core, and I imagine that the others are in the same ballpark whereas C++ will be a couple of orders faster.  I've used Perl for this type of rapid prototyping before, but +1 on the general comments about C/C++ for prod algos.  44Khz 1x is ~100 opcodes/sample, and this might be tight for many algos.

Comment: @TerryE: Oh im sure they are in the same ball park its just my impression that Ruby and Python are faster than PHP when not directly acting as a web application - but this is just an impression ive never seen nor researched any benchmarks.

Comment: There are tools which transform PHP into lower level languages. HipHop for PHP might help you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input on this one.

I rewrote the thing in C++ and can now perform the above actions in less than a second.

I'd never have thought that the speed difference is that huge (compiled application is ~40X faster).

Comment: It's been a while, I'd guess that by using PHP 7.2 you could get 5-10 times better performance in comparison to what you used.  PHP became one of the fastest programming languages, aside from native ones like C/c++.